# Downloading CPQ Quote documents using the REST API

Tags: rest-api, api, cpq

I'm trying to write a small automation bridging Salesforce CPQ and a third-party vendor.

The workflow I would like to address is to (i) generate a CPQ Quote document and (ii) save the generated PDF locally to then send this file somewhere else.

To automate this I need to access the generated PDF quote document using Salesforce REST API but I couldn't find a way to access the data blob like I was used to do with normal Salesforce files (i.e. ContentDocument and ContentVersion).

The only way I can get these documents is to click the 'view' button and download manually the file locally and I need to automate this step.

Does anyone know a way to access these CPQ documents using Salesforce API ?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.cpq_dev_api.meta/cpq_dev_api/cpq_api_generate_proposal.htm

Comment: Thank you for this but I had already evaluated that API and there is nothing that points to the generated PDF in the endpoint response body, only the id of the async job that is going to generate it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will work for you exactly, but there is a field on the quote document object that stores the id of the PDF document. Once the async job is complete, you can query the new quote document (`SBQQ__QuoteDocument__c`) for the `SBQQ__ViewRecordId__c` field. This will return the ID of the attachment or document id. You can then retrieve it from the appropriate object using another API call.